# how do I find duplicate serial numbers in 2 separate columns in Microsoft access?

Tags: ms-access

I am having an issue with Microsoft access running a query and don't know how to go about running the query I need. i am trying to find duplicate S/N's in 2 columns, for example

```
COMPUTER SN     HARD DR SN       MONITOR 1 SN      MONITOR 2 SN
1               456              123               654
2               528              234               758
3               963              654               234
```

as shown above computer 3 is showing the same monitor from both 1 and 2 and I can get Microsoft access to show duplicates from up and down or side by side and I cant figure out how to do diagonal as well. I am using Microsoft access 2016 and any help would be great thank you. I have been looking for the past few days and I don't know what SQL is or how to do that in access but everything I can find shows me how to do up and down (I got that working) or direct side by side (I got that working as well) nothing showing me how to do diagonal as well.

Comment: So you're not familiar with SQL yet have this question? What is it for, school, course, otherwise?

Comment: it is for work. I am helping someone else create a quick query to find duplicate items. I just don't know what SQL stands for I am trying to teach myself coding and am able to read it but I don't know all of the commands and the correct format to use. I am sure I have heard of SQL but am unsure.

Comment: I just looked it up SQL is a language of coding like LUA or C++, but I still don't know how to use it. I know how to start creating a macro but I don't know the language of how to type it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had someone else from my work come up and help and we created a query with this in the comment block,

In (SELECT [MONITOR 2] FROM [COMPUTER S/N] WHERE [COMPUTER S/N].[MONITOR 2] NOT IN ("NA")) And Not In ("NA")

and had monitor 1 as the column selected. so it will take each S/N from monitor 1 and check monitor 2 for the same data, then I have to have another query for each column duplicates. the end phrase and not in ("NA") is only to take out the spots where people only have one monitor.